# Не работает выравнивание по центру text-align: center

Tags: html5, css3

Есть код:

```html
<div class="main" style="background: #acdf43; text-align: center;">
  <div class="cent" style="display: table;">
    <div class="l1" style="display: table-cell; background: #aaa;">123123123123123123123123123
      <br>321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321
      <br>111111111111111111
      <br>222222
      <br>333333333</div>
    <div class="l2" style="display: table-cell; background: #f00; vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%; width: 100px;">000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы блок cent был выровнен по центру.
Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: результат]

Answer (score 1):

Блочные элементы не получится выровнять через `text-align`. Добавьте `margin` к классу `cent` с отступами по правому и левому краю, как `auto`.

```
<div class="main" style="background: #acdf43;">
    <div class="cent" style="display: table; margin: 0 auto 0 auto;">
        <div class="l1" style="display: table-cell; background: #aaa;">123123123123123123123123123<br>321321321321321321321321321321321321321321321<br>111111111111111111<br>222222<br>333333333</div>
        <div class="l2" style="display: table-cell; background: #f00; vertical-align: bottom; height: 100%; width: 100px;">000</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос удалось решить через display: inline-table + родительский элемент оставить text-align: center. Насколько мой код итоговый вообще кросс-браузерный?

Answer (score 1):

Text align не работает с блочным елементом

`.cent {
     margin: 0 auto;
  }`

либо дочерним элементам задайте значение display: inline-block